# Explanation of weird values in New Horizons data?

Tags: mathematics, new-horizons, remote-sensing, 2014-mu69

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33223/27793) I computed (methods given later in post) the estimated time, distance, range, and resolution for the science capture for New Horizon's closest approach to Ultima Thule (2014 MU69).

While looking through the images on APL's website I noticed a discrepancy in one set of values.  Specifically, the numbers given for **Range** for all of the LORRI images from Ultima Thule on that site appear to <strike>be about 6.5 times too large</strike> bear no relation to the computed range.  All of the rest of my results seem consistent except for that figure.  Can anyone explain why I'm seeing a discrepancy?

**An image detail screen with anomolous value highlighted**
[image: Screenshot with value in question highlighted]
<sup>Source: [LORRI Images from the Ultima Thule Flyby](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/), NASA/JHU APL/SwRI, linked-to full-size image [here](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/data/mu69/level2/lor/jpeg/040862/lor_0408624825_0x630_sci_7.jpg)

Filter by REQID: **KELR_MU69_CA04-MAP_L1_2019001** then look for **lor_0408624825_0x630_sci_7.jpg** in the results</sup>

To be clear, I'm focusing one image here but I've seen similar for **all** of the LORRI images at Ultima Thule.

Here's a sample of my results for the time around when the above image was taken.  Everything matches except for **Range** where I get ~28000 km and they list "182,686" (with no units given).  For the Pluto encounter they used Mkm so having the units for this be km would make sense.  <strike>The value they show though is about 6.5 times larger than what I computed.</strike>  The "range" given doesn't seem at all related to the actual distance (or at least not consistently between image sequences).  I tried miles, feet, etc. but nothing (except tenths-of-a-mile) comes close to fitting.  Any ideas?  Is it in in tenths-of-a-mile?  Have I missed something obvious?

### Summary of values

Below is a comparison of the values from the above example (taken during CA04) with those I computed (discrepancy in bold):

`Value         Published     Computed`
`SCET          05:01:47      04:56 to 05:06`
`Distance      not given     -31900 to -23100 km`
**`Range         182,686       32100 to 23350 km`**
`Resolution    ~140 m/px     159 to 115 m/px`

Other images from the Ultima Thule encounter show similar discrepancies.

Here's a comparison with the preliminary schedule for a point during CA04:

`Value         Published     Computed`
`Time          K-2000 s      -2209 to -1600 s`
`Distance      ~-28800 km    -31900 to -23100 km`

**Update**: The "range" values for the raw images don't appear to be tenths-of-miles.  They also don't seem to go in sequence between observation sets (CA01, CA04, etc.) but they *do* go in sequence within a set.  Maybe it's something to do with transmit time or distance?

`Image  Time                 Range (raw)  Range (processed)  Notes`             
`1      2019-01-01 05:01:47  182,686      28000 km/17000 mi  Part of CA04 sequence`
`2      2019-01-01 04:22:19  148,795      61000 km/38000 mi  Part of CA01 sequence`
`3      2018-12-31 09:38:13  826,749      N/A                Last approach image`   
`4      2018-12-31 07:02:03  961,979      N/A                First "odd" image`   
`5      2018-12-30 16:56:06  2 Mkm        N/A                Last image with km`

- Processed images [here](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Galleries/Featured-Images/image.php?page=1&gallery_id=2&image_id=580) or [here](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Galleries/Featured-Images/image.php?page=1&gallery_id=2&image_id=579)
- Raw images linked from [here](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/):
  1: `KELR_MU69_CA04-MAP_L1_2019001   lor_0408624825_0x630_sci_7.jpg`
  2: `KELR_MU69_CA01-MAP_L1_2019001   lor_0408622457_0x630_sci_6.jpg`
  3: `KELR_MU69_APROTL_L14_2018365D   lor_0408555011_0x630_sci_9.jpg`
  4: `KELR_MU69_APROTL_L1_2018365A    lor_0408545641_0x630_sci_9.jpg`
  5: `KELR_MU69_ROTCOVER_L1_2018364B  lor_0408494884_0x630_sci_7.jpg`

### My methodology

- **Velocity** Velocity in km/s relative to closest approach point
  (source data)
  Taken from [here](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Mission/Where-is-New-Horizons.php) (as of 2018-12-31)

  $V = 14.44\ \frac{\mathsf{km}}{\mathsf{s}}$
- **Distance** Distance in km to point of closest approach
  (source data)
  Estimated from distances shown in the **Imaging schedule** diagram (see below). Negative for approach, positive for departure. Accuracy is about ±50 km.  Note that UT's position is ±4000 km; I ignore this margin of error (assume it to be 0).

  $D = value\ estimated\ from\ diagram$
- **Time** Seconds relative to closest approach
  (computed value)

  $T = \frac{D}{V}$
- **SCET** Spacecraft Event Time on 2019-01-01
  Derived from time based on closest approach of 05:33:30 SCET (based on "05:33" from [here](http://planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2018/what-to-expect-new-horizons-mu69-ultima-thule.html)). Format is `hh:mm`.  [JHUAPL](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/) gives a more precise value of "05:33:00" which is 30 seconds earlier than what I used in my calculations.
- **Field of view** For LORRI
  (source data)

  $FOV = 0.29\mathsf{°} \approx 0.005061455\ \mathsf{rad}$
- **Closest-approach distance**
  (source data)
  Value is currently estimated as 3540 km; value used is 3500 km.

  $D_{min} = 3500\ \mathsf{km}$
- **Range** Distance in km from spacecraft to 2014 MU69
  (computed value, **inconsistent with published values**)
  Values shown in table are rounded.

  $R = \sqrt{{D}^2 + {D_{min}}^2}$

  Note that image resolution is computed from this.  That result matches the published values.
- **Width of view** View width in meters on a perpendicular plane at the range of Ultima Thule
  (computed value)

  $W = 2 \cdot 1000 \frac{\mathsf{m}}{\mathsf{km}} \cdot \tan{\frac{FOV}{2}} \cdot R$
- **Sensor size** LORRI sensor size in pixels for 1×1 mode
  (source data)

  $S = 1024\ \mathsf{pixels}$
- **Resolution** In meters per pixel
  (computed value)

  $resolution = \frac{W}{S}$

---

**Ultima Thule imaging schedule**
[image: Ultima Thule flyby imaging schedule]
<sup>Source: [Ultima Thule Flyby Press Kit](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/News-Center/Resources/Press-Kits/NewHorizonsPressKit__UT.pdf), p. 25, NASA/JHUAPL/SwRI

(cropped, edges cleaned up)</sup>

**Preliminary Ultima Thule imaging schedule**
[image: Preliminary Ultima Thule flyby imaging schedule]
<sup>Source: [Earth-Based Support for the New Horizons Kuiper Extended Mission](http://guinan.space.swri.edu/nhcs/files/dps_2016_kem_WS_Final.pdf), p.7, NASA/SWRI

(cropped, edited to remove page number)</sup>

Comment: As of 2019-01-17, the page has been updated with range figures more in line with what you've calculated

Answer (score 5):

I've looked through your numbers, and they do seem to be correct. The range values included are likely intended to be in km, but seem to be inaccurate. The range values are not official at this point in time, and do not have access to the spacecraft ephemeris data yet. I suspect when that data comes down the range values will be estimated better.

Bottom line, both the range and the distance based on the size give similar values, for the highest resolution photographs, both of which are very far off of the values provided. In fact, the values are obviously wrong, the larger, and therefore closer, picture has a larger range then the smaller target.

Doing some further analysis, I believe the range values are assuming a closest approach of about 01:30 SCET. That is 4 hours off, which just happens to be the 4 hours difference that EDT is from UTC. My guess is that they had the time zone wrong for the range estimates, and never noticed it. Here's a plot of what the data looks like, assuming a negative range after the closest approach. Seems pretty linear to me. I mentioned this to [Alan Stern on Twitter](https://twitter.com/whereisroadster/status/1081203933492756480), hopefully they can address it.

[image]

Comment: That seems quite plausible to me.  Between the CA01 and CA04 images I'm computing a Δd of 32891 km using the raw image numbers and a Δd of 33000km using the processed image numbers.  The latter is only good to 2 significant digits so the deltas are essentially identical.  I too get a Δt of 4.0 hours between the two sets of values at 2 significant digits.

Comment: I think Alan Stern is going to have someone look at this, he at least acknowledged there seems to be something off, so hopefully it will be corrected soon!

Comment: Great analysis!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: As of 2019-01-17, the page has been updated with range figures more in line with what you've calculated.

---

According to the [JHUAPL website](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/soc/UltimaThule-Encounter/) (click on 'Learn more about these images ', for some reason a direct link didn't work), range should be in km:

> The following ancillary information is provided for each image posted: the date of the observation in coordinated universal time (UTC) at the New Horizons spacecraft, the exposure time of the image in milliseconds, the name of the target, the range to the target in kilometers (i.e., the distance between the New Horizons spacecraft and the target; for example, 12.1M km means 12.1 million kilometers), and the root filename of the image.

You're deriving the range from the timestamp. Are you sure there's no discrepancy there? I thought it might be a difference between spacecraft local time and received-on-Earth time, but that's not it: you'd be 6 hours out then. 
A difference of 100,000 km translates to about 2 hours of flight time (at 14 km/s).

[Directory and file name in PDS](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/holdings/nh-x-lorri-2-launch-v3.0/dataset.html):

They seem to be using the same file name convention on the JHUAPL site. Directory names are not visible.

data/YYYYMMDD_METMET/lor_metmetmetm_0xaaa_ttt_v.sfx

> The data are all stored as file pairs of one detached PDS label and one FITS file per exposure. The directory and file names are delimited by underscores and slashes as demonstrated above:

- YYYYMMDD is year, month and day-of-month; METMET is the first six digits of the ten-digit MET clock (Mission Event Time; ~spacecraft seconds since launch);
- **lor** is the prefix for LORRI data;
- **metmetmetm** is the full ten-digit MET of the image;
- **0xaaa** is the Application (Process) Identifier (ApID) for the telemetry data packet type;
- **ttt** is either eng or sci for EDR or RDR data;
- **v** is a version number; (for the UT encounter, this seems to be used to identify image strips that can be stitched together - Hobbes)
- sfx is fit or lbl for the FITS or PDS label file (or file extension on the JHUAPL site - Hobbes)

[ApID](https://pds-smallbodies.astro.umd.edu/catalogs/NewHorizons/lorri.cat):

LORRI high-rate image data telemetry APID definitions

```
         C&DH  binning                                                    
  APID   side  mode    compression type                                   

  0x630    1    1x1    lossless                                           
  0x631    1    1x1    packetized                                         
  0x632    1    1x1    lossy                                              
  0x633    1    4x4    lossless                                           
  0x634    1    4x4    packetized                                         
  0x635    1    4x4    lossy                                              
  0x636    2    1x1    lossless                                           
  0x637    2    1x1    packetized                                         
  0x638    2    1x1    lossy                                              
  0x639    2    4x4    lossless                                           
  0x63A    2    4x4    packetized                                         
  0x63B    2    4x4    lossy
```

Comment: "'You're deriving the range from the timestamp. Are you sure there's no discrepancy there?"  I thought that might be the case but the preliminary schedule includes both time and distance and they match closely to what I got.

Comment: Can you glean any metadata from the example above? ( REQID: `KELR_MU69_CA04-MAP_L1_2019001`, filename `lor_0408624825_0x630_sci_7.jpg`) I'm guessing `KELR_MU69_CA04`=Kepler object MU69, close acquisition sequence #4, `MAP_L1`=???, `2019001`=day 1 of 2019, `lor`=LORRI, the rest=???

Comment: Slight clarification: In my original calculations I computed time from distance.  I did compute distance from time for some of my sanity checks though.