# Is New Horizons' transmission of data from the Arrokoth flyby completed?

Tags: new-horizons, data-transmission

I have followed the news on the New Horizons web page for years, searched the web several times, the last time just before asking: There seems to be no information available whether all data from the Arrokoth flyby have already been transmitted by New Horizons. It was said after the flyby that transmission would be completed by the end of 2020, but I have not heard anything later.

Comment: This is a good question and I don't know the answer. It has already sent back newer data taken post-Arrokoth flyby: [Distance to Proxima Centauri (Gaia VS New Horizons parallax program)](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34994/7982) and [How well could the New Horizons spacecraft localize itself in space in 3D using parallax?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49965/12102) and [Was a “spare LORRI” camera available to take matching image on Earth the same time New Horizons took the parallax image from the Kuiper belt?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/46811/12102)

Comment: @uhoh As a follower of New Horizons' web site, I know about these activities, but their data could be transmitted before transmission of those of the Arrokoth flyby ended. I found where the completion of the transmission was announced: At the end of [this page](http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/Arrokoth/Arrokoth.php)

Comment: I asked this exact question to Alan Stern multiple times on Twitter. I know he saw it since he liked it, but I received no answer so far.

Comment: @compi I see only one logical explanation: The transmission has not yet ended and it is not known sufficiently precisely when it will end. Anyway, I would like to have an answer...

Comment: @Helmut According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Horizons#Data_download) the download should have been completed since September last year.
Either it hasn't ended yet or something went wrong... We will see :)

Answer (score 7):

From http://pluto.jhuapl.edu/News-Center/PI-Perspectives.php

"Once New Horizons exits hibernation, our pace of activity will pick up dramatically. We’ll begin by downlinking the science data from hibernation and the final few gigabits of data from our encounter with the Kuiper Belt object Arrokoth."

That hibernation is set to complete on 1 March 2023, so still some time to go.