# Where can I read about Lucy's complete propulsion system?

Tags: propulsion, design, mission-design, deep-space, lucy-asteroid-mission

Wikipedia's [/Lucy (spacecraft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucy_(spacecraft)) says nothing of propulsion, and it's SWRI home page for the spacecraft http://lucy.swri.edu/mission/Spacecraft.html gives specification and enumerates what's on Lucy’s instrument pointing platform (IPP) , but is silent on things like propulsion, attitude control, navigation, etc. Here are the specifications:

```
LUCY SPECIFICATIONS

Width:                      46.75 ft (14.25 m)
Height:                     23.6 ft (7.2 m) or 12.4 (3.8m) when solar panels are stored)
Depth:                      9.12 ft (2.78 m)
Diameter of Solar Panels:   23.9 ft (7.3 m)
Dry Mass (unfueled):        1810 lbs (821 kg)
Wet Mass (fueled):          3417 lbs (1550 kg)
Power:                      504 watts at the furthest encounter
```

Fuel is 47% of the mass, so this is a "[flying fuel tank](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/23026/12102)"-class spacecraft, with a larger fuel fraction than the electrically propulsed [DAWN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawn_(spacecraft)) but well below the 60 to 70% of the winners.

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33972/12102) to *What propulsion will Lucy use for its deep space maneuvers?* cites only an article about a different mission that mentions conventional propulsion for Lucy in passing, then speculates further.

**Question:**

1. Where can I read about Lucy's complete propulsion system?
2. If the answer is "you can't" then please answer instead "Why not, *I paid for it!?* (a little at least)"

Refining Lucy Mission Delta-V During Spacecraft Design Using Trajectory Optimization Within High Fidelity Monte Carlo Maneuver Analysis (Preprint) AAS 19-614

**update:** I found the words "bipropellant main engine" in [Refining Lucy Mission Delta-V During Spacecraft Design Using Trajectory Optimization Within High Fidelity Monte Carlo Maneuver Analysis (Preprint) AAS 19-614](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20190029152/downloads/20190029152.pdf) J. V. McAdams et al. (2019??) along with some uncertainties in delta-v that might offer some clues.

---

Several major Deep Space Maneuvers (DSMs) shown in [Lucy: Navigating a Jupiter Trojan Tour, AAS 17-632](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323228730_Lucy_Navigating_a_Jupiter_Trojan_Tour) D. Stanbridge et al.

[image: Several major Deep Space Maneuvers (DSMs) shown in "Lucy: Navigating a Jupiter Trojan Tour", AAS 17-632]

Comment: More about Lucy: [How will Lucy “make use” of a deep space atomic clock?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/49946/12102)

Comment: Yes, AAS19 was a conference in (August) 2019. It was the AIAA/AAS Astrodynamics Specialist Conference, held in Portland, Maine.

Comment: @ChrisR *Thanks!* are the proceedings published? In a place where I can read them?

Comment: yes! The 2019 conference proceedings with titles and abstracts are available here: https://space-flight.org/docs/2019_summer/2019_summer.html. All of the AAS/AIAA conference proceedings are here: https://www.space-flight.org/conferences.html. However, you might need to purchase copies of the papers themselves, albeit lots of authors republish their papers on their websites. Therefore, searching the paper number usually leads to good results.

Comment: @ChrisR I'm off to the library today then, thanks!

Comment: Rocketdyne made a press release stating there are "eight MR-103J thrusters and six MR-106L" on Lucy. The latter 6x 22N thrust could be the main engines?
https://www.rocket.com/media/news-features/aerojet-rocketdyne-propel-lucy-first-ever-mission-study-trojan-asteroids

Comment: Nammo (makers of LEROS series engines) claims Lucy uses the [LEROS-1c](https://www.nammo.com/product/leros-1c/)